Issues with NGINX rewrite capturing last part of URL & matching first part
I have an NGINX rewrite/return block as follows:
if ($request_uri ~ /product-category/(.*)/$) {
   return 301 /shop/?categories[]=$1;
}

This correctly matches https://example.com/product-category/cat-1/ and redirects that to https://example.com/shop/?categories[]=cat-1.
But, I have a few URLS that have a variable number of directories between the product-category and final cat-1, i.e.
https://example.com/product-category/parent/cat-1/
https://example.com/product-category/gparent/parent/cat-1/
https://example.com/product-category/distant-relative/gparent/parent/cat-1/
...

I am looking for a rewrite or return rule that would match any URL that starts with product-category after the domain, extracts the very last directory name, and compiles my redirect like in the first example.
Said another way, I need some way for all of the URLs in my second example above to redirect to https://example.com/shop/?categories[]=cat-1 no matter how many ancestor directories may exist between the product-category and final directory.
Any advice would be super appreciated.

Try: ^/product-category/(?:.*/)?([^/]+)/$

@RichardSmith, yes! That worked wonderfully. If you'd like to add your comment above as an answer, I can mark it as "Accepted". If you have a moment to explain the regex behind your answer, that would also be amazing.

Try: ^/product-category/(?:.*/)?([^/]+)/$

The $request_uri variable contains the path and query parts of the original URL.
In your examples, it always begins with /product-category/ and ends with / and may contain any number of path segments in between.
The solution breaks down as follows:

^/product-category/
(?:.*/)?
([^/]+)
/$

Step (1) matches the path segment at the beginning (hence the start of string anchor ^).
Step (2) is a non-capturing group that matches any text that ends with a /, including text containing multiple /s, and will therefore consume one or more path segments. We add a trailing ? to make it optional, so it also matches zero path segments.
Step (3) captures $1, which is the text between two /s.
Step (4) completes the expression with the final / and the end of string anchor.
This solution assumes that there is no query string or separating ?.
